# Redux store - Accessing keys of an object when not using arrays

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a redux store like so:

```
 {
  '1f458697-e2c0-4d11-ada0-ee7b113c2429': {
    name: 'Jim',
    title: 'Developer',
    active: true
  },
  '4498eb08-3786-495a-a66c-21a65138ab24': {
    name: 'Darren',
    title: 'Human Resources',
    active: false
  },
  'c7975551-153f-4eab-a875-ed5445f76252': {
    name: 'Francesa',
    title: 'Chief of Internal Operations',
    active: false
  }
}
```

And I have a selector that gets an active user.

```
export const getActiveUser = (users) => _.find(users, { 'active': true });
```

My question is, whats the nicest way to include the ID of the user in the payload to use within my React component:

1. Is this is a bad practice and a sign that I should be using an array instead.
2. Should I just change my user payload to include the ID. This feels wrong as I would be duplicating data.
3. Should I manipulate that specific selector to include the users ID.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use arrays for table-like data and [`filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#filter) function for filtering the result set (if multiple users can be active at a time). If only one user can be active at a time, consider changing the db schema and create a separate variable `activeUserId` instead of having all of them contain unnecessary payload (and change the shape of the redux store accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

**- Is this is a bad practice and a sign that I should be using an array
   instead.**

Normalizing the data, so you can edit or delete items (users in your case) in O(1) is a good approach, which is also covered in the Dan Abramov's [idiomatic redux course](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-normalizing-the-state-shape?course=building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux).

**- Should I just change my user payload to include the ID. This feels wrong as I would be duplicating data.**

Since you don't usually change IDs, adding them inside the user's object should not be a problem, and it should give you quick access to the ID. However, if you don't won't to duplicate that's acceptable as well.

**- Should I manipulate that specific selector to include the users ID.**

Part of the the selectors role is to create derived data, just like what you do when you filter the users. So if you want to the the ID to each user, this is a good place to do so. Don't mutate the objects, just create new user objects with ID. However, if you've got lots of users, you should use [memoized selectors](http://memoized%20selectors) or add the ID as part of the payload to prevent performance issues.